# How do while loops work with class attributes

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        # Move to the tail (the last node)
        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)
        return
```

I'm a little confused on how the while loops statement works in this context. While loops are suppose to work as long as the condition is true. I am not sure how the while loop condition would return true or false in this context can someone please explain. Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.next` evaluates to a value, and that value is then evaluated as a boolean.

Specifically, if `node.next = None`, `bool(None) == False` and the loop breaks. Otherwise `bool(<Node object>) == True` and the loop proceeds.